# error while passing the value to the imageView dynamically in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsstring

In my app, i am having the image name in a variable, and I pass the value to the imageView as below

```
productsView.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageString]];
```

The image is not getting displayed,
I have printed my imagestring,

```
 NSLog("%@",imageString);// It gets printed in log as myImage.png
```

But if I give the value directly, it works with out any mistake

```
productsView.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myimage.png"]];
```

Can anyone help me please

Comment: In your variable name, is it having .png representation?

Comment: ya , it gets printed in log as myImage.png

Comment: I have passed an array of objects to it, accordig to the row selected in the previous view'

Comment: Try using productsView.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageString];

Comment: Why don't you try to put the string value direct in the imageNamed: instead of create a new NSString

Comment: There may be some case sensitive problem. Please check whether it is a case sensitive.

Comment: no, actually i am getting the image name from the previous page, so I have to do like this only

Comment: ya, the image name is correct

Comment: @Chandru Did you see my answer? Is this useful to you or give comment what you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think small mistake. From Your comment, image name should be

```
imageString = @"myimage.png", not @"myImage.png".
```

Comment: what does it mean? You get as `myimage.png`? yet I've seen updated your question as `myImage.png` in first log. But when you directly given, assigned name as `myimage.png`..

Comment: actually, my error is that, I have 3 rows in a table in the first row, then when I click on the row, it will move to the next view and an image will be printed on the view according to the row clicked, if i press 2nd or 3 rd ro, it is working, if i press first row it is not working

Comment: then according to your point, image name will be passed to Second VC by selected index. Am I right? If yes, show your array of image name?

Comment: NSArray * imageArrayForProduct=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"wine.png",@"whisky.png",@"food.png", nil];

Comment: countryViewController.imageString=productImageString;

Comment: When you select other two images, it got displayed. Am I right? In the sense, code mentioned above which is working perfectly. check with your image whether it is correctly added with your project or not. And check also with your image name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46669/discussion-between-chandru-and-mani)